# Find object property that contains a given string

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I understand that I can go through an object and find a given property if I know the name of the property. If I want to find object.foo, I can use object['foo'].

Let's say I'm unable to control the way the data is structured, there's roughly 100 properties and I need to only pull out all of the properties that start with the string 'ninja' but I don't know the full names of the properties. object.ninjaSword, object.ninjaStar, object.ninjaFavoriteFood, etc.

How do I pull the properties that start with 'ninja'? Thanks in advance and my apologies up front if it's been answered and I missed it during my searching. :/

Comment: Object.keys(object).filter(function(prop){return prop.indexOf('ninja')==0})

Comment: Thanks for the quick help and clear answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to iterate through *all properties* and filter those that match your requirement.

For example:

```
// iterate over all properties
for (var name in obj) {
    // check if the name starts with 'ninja'
    if (name.indexOf('ninja') === 0) {
        // found a property that starts with 'ninja', so log the property
        // name, and the respective value
        console.log(name, obj[name]);
    }
}
```

The `Object` type also has a method called [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which will return an array of all property names of the object. You could then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that to get all properties that match your requirement again. And then you could loop over those and also get the property values.